# Sublime Text 3 weirdly reindents html

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Let's say I have this HTML layout in Sublime:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1>
hello
</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to reindent it, and I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>
            hello
        </h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I want this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>
                hello
            </h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

ie I want `<head>` and `<body>` to display as children of `<html>` instead of being on the same level. Is there an inbuilt way of changing this?

Comment: I indented my HTML code like this too at the beggining. The problem is that you have 1 level of indentation for your entire code, which is pretty annoying on small screen. You're just "wasting" your screen IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the [indentation rules](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/d694a0b1ac222c3de998ede23c380898b165136b/HTML/Miscellaneous.tmPreferences) that ST3 uses to indent the HTML.

1. Install [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) if it is not already installed
2. Open the Command Palette
3. Type `PRV: O` and select `PackageResourceViewer - Open Resource`
4. Select `HTML`
5. Select `Miscellaneous.tmPreferences`
6. Remove the `(?!html)` in `batchDecreaseIndentPattern`
7. Remove the `|html` in `batchIncreaseIndentPattern`
8. Save the file

Answer (score 1):

Solved. What I did was install [HTMLBeautify](https://github.com/rareyman/HTMLBeautify), then set up a custom command:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SaveRegime(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        if "html" in self.window.active_view().settings().get("syntax").lower():
            self.window.run_command("html_beautify")
        else:
            self.window.run_command("reindent")
```

It's not pretty, but it works.